# Eclipse and cronTriggered jobs debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, crontrigger

I have a webapp developped in Java, using GWT, Spring and Hibernate.

This app has a cronTriggered job (which extends QuartzJobBean), set in a application-context.xml file.

How do I debug that job (which is triggered to run every minute) ?

I have tried to set breakpoints in the method executeInternal() of the job class (I am using Eclipse Java EE Helios), but they don't seem to be reached.

Comment: I had selected poor man's way SOPs

Answer (score 1):

Change how the app is started to include the remote debugging agent.  That way, you can attach to it from Eclipse.  Once attached, it should respond to breakpoints set within Eclipse and from there you are in a typical debugging session.  Be aware if the app uses timeouts, they can trigger while you are stopped at a breakpoint which can make it difficult to continue execution afterwards.